# Unable to make a Picture appear in a sharepoint list custom view

Tags: json, list, sharepoint

I'm trying to reproduce this custom list on my sharepoint communication website :
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples/birthday-format

I modified the source code to adapt it and here is what I have :

```html
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideListHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "display": "flex",
      "flex-wrap": "wrap",
      "align-items": "stretch",
      "padding": "8px",
      "margin-bottom": "25px",
      "max-width": "420px",
      "border-radius": "8px",
      "box-shadow": "4px 4px 8px lightblue"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "class": "ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "flex-grow": "1",
          "display": "flex",
          "flex-wrap": "wrap",
          "align-items": "stretch",
          "max-width": "310px"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "flex": "none"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "width": "100px",
                  "height": "100px",
                  "overflow": "hidden",
                  "border-radius": "50%",
                  "margin-right": "8px"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "img",
                    "attributes": {
                      "src": "=if([$Picture] == '', @currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M',[$Picture])",
                      "title": "=if([$Picture] == '', 'No picture available', [$Picture.desc])"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "position": "relative",
                      "top": "50%",
                      "left": "50%",
                      "width": "100%",
                      "height": "auto",
                      "margin-left": "-50%",
                      "margin-top": "-50%"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "flex-grow": "1",
              "display": "flex",
              "flex-direction": "column",
              "flex-wrap": "nowrap",
              "align-items": "stretch",
              "max-width": "130px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "flex-grow": "1"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "txtContent": "[$Nomtxt]",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "block"
                    },
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontSize-l ms-fontWeight-semibold ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "txtContent": "[$Title]",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "=if([$Title] == '', 'none', 'block')"
                    },
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontSize-m ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "display": "flex",
          "flex-direction": "column",
          "max-width": "310px",
          "min-width": "95px"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "flex-grow": "1"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "style": {
                  "display": "=if([$DateB] <= @now,'block','none')"
                },
                "attributes": {
                  "iconName": "BirthdayCake"
                }
              },
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "style": {
                  "display": "block"
                },
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontWeight-semibold ms-fontSize-m"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if([$Today_Date] == [$BirthdayD],'Happy Birthday!', 'Next Birthday')"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "style": {
                  "display": "=if([$DateB] == '', 'none', 'block')",
                  "padding-left": "0px",
                  "font-size": "14px"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$DisplayBirth]",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontSize-s ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
                }
              },
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "style": {
                  "display": "=if([$DateB] == '', 'block', 'none')",
                  "padding-left": "8px"
                },
                "txtContent": "No Birthday Entered",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontSize-s ms-fontWeight-semilight ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "flex": "none",
              "display": "flex",
              "flex-direction": "row-reverse",
              "flex-wrap": "nowrap"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Unfornatly, when the "Picture" field is not empty, the Picture won't appear :

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X45cE.png)

Here I've just put an image to my row.

I don't know what to do to fix this.
If you have any information of solution to this problem please help.

Thanks,
Yannick Creton

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might also try sharepoint.stackechange.com for SharePoint questions.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

The Picture column needs to be of the type Hyperlink.
[image]

## Reasoning

Most likely, you used the type "Image". Image might seem correct. And, it's in the default list of column types to choose from. However, the JSON code sample from GitHub and the modified version you link to both depend on the column returning the address of an image.

When I tried the sample with a column of type Image, it failed. When I tried it with the Hyperlink it worked. Add a column of that type from "+ Add column > Hyperlink"

## Background

I suspect the reason the author of the sample used the Hyperlink type instead of the Image type is that the Image type is relatively new. Previously, the Hyperlink type was called "Hyperlink or Picture". `[The official reference on List and library column types][1]` shows the "Hyperlink and Image" type in the "Classic" section.

Answer (score 0):

To make the picture appear, you need to add .serverRelativeUrl when you are setting the source.

Change this:

```
"src": "=if([$Picture] == '', @currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M',[$Picture])"
```

To this:

```
"src": "=if([$Picture] == '', @currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M',[$Picture.serverRelativeUrl])"
```